# Getting 403 Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup. on YouTube API with already API Key

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube-api, google-oauth

I've developed a WordPress plugin to pull videos from YouTube with the YouTube v3 API

The plugin works fine in most sites but currently I'm having an issue with one, I can't seem to pass the error:

**"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."**

The weird thing is I can copy / paste the query with a valid API key on the browser and it works, I've tested with other Api Keys with the same results. It seems the problem is with that server

I've checked than other plugins were using the Google API, but disabled all of them and still getting the same error

I don't know what to do next

Here is an example of a basic query to the YouTube API

```
$request = new WP_Http;
$result = $request->request( 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=USERNAME&key=API_KEY', 
        array( 
            'method' => 'GET',
            'headers' => array('Accept' => 'application/json' )
        )  
);
```

The request is handled by the native WordPress class [WP_Http](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http/request/)

Comment: Welcome to stack: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  For anyone to help you debug an issue in your code you need to post the code a. Ideally a small example that can show the error or how you are making your request.

Comment: Whats the URL you use to retrieve data? Are you pasting the API key after the 'key' parameter? Could you share the code you are using to retrieve the data from the API?

Comment: Hello DalmTo, thanks, i've just added an example of a request, hope it makes it clear!

Comment: Hello janykste, yes I always add the api key as a last parameter on the query to the server, if I copy the generated request url to the browser I can se a good response, the problem seems to be when Is done with the WP_Http in this specific server. Thanks!

Comment: That error message has one of two meanings. If you are accessing a resource with a free quota, then you've exceeded that quota. OR the resource you are accessing requires OAuth authorization.

Comment: As I have read to access the YouTube data you'll need an api key or an OAuth authorization, the problem is I'm sure the key is valid as tested on other servers work, the only problem is when used from that especific one, could it be any other plugin is using the google API and conflicting with mine?